# Derivate of absolute value of complex valued function

Tags: complex-analysis, derivatives

I have a derivate where $a(z)$ is complex valued.

$$\frac{da(z)}{dz}=-\Delta a(z)-\Delta^*e^{-2i\omega z/\bar{c}}b(z)$$
where $\Delta=\frac{\sigma}{2\bar{\zeta}}-\frac{i\omega\nu}{2\bar{c}}$ and star denotes conjugate.

I want to calculate

$$\frac{d|a|^2}{dz}=2Re(a\frac{da}{dz}).$$

The answer is

$$-(\Delta+\Delta^*)|a|^2-\Delta^*e^{-2i\omega z/\bar{c}}ba^*-\Delta e^{2i\omega z/\bar{c}}b^*a$$

Could someone explain how this is achieved?

Comment: You can solve the differential equation for $a$, then use that

Comment: This wouldn't work. $a$ and $b$ are functions dependent on $z$.

Comment: Ahh ok I wasn't aware $b$ was a function. I'll have a look at this again in a little while

Comment: Sorry, I'll edit to make it clearer.

Comment: Is $a$ holomorphic?

Comment: @denklo yes....

Comment: Is $\partial_z |a|^2 = 2Re(a\partial_z a)$ even true then? $\partial_z |a|^2 = \partial_z a^\ast a = a^\ast\partial_z a$, since $a^\ast$ does not depend on $z$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see this from the product rule.$$\begin{align}\frac{d|a|^2}{dz}=a^*\frac{da}{dz}+a\frac{da^*}{dz}&=a^*(-\Delta a-\Delta^*e^{-2i\omega z/\bar{c}}b)+a(-\Delta^* a^*-\Delta e^{2i\omega z/\bar{c}}b^*)\\&=-(\Delta+\Delta^*)|a|^2-\Delta^*e^{-2i\omega z/\bar{c}}ba^*-\Delta e^{2i\omega z/\bar{c}}b^*a\end{align}$$

Comment: Just curious, how do you get $\partial_z a^\ast$ from $\partial_z a$ this way? I'd think $(\partial_z a)^\ast = \partial_{z^\ast}a^\ast ? $

Comment: @denklo I see where you're coming from. I think to explain how I think this works, its best to use an example. If $f(z)=(1+i)z$, then $f^*=f^*(z)=(1-i)z$, rather than $f^*=f^*(z^*)=(1-i)z^*$. I.e, you just complex conjugate the function itself, rather than the argument of the function.

Comment: Got it,thanks! +1

Comment: Thanks for this answer...so dumb not to see this!